# Is there a way for me to write a script in Robot Framework that utilize's the command line functions?

Tags: testing, automation, robotframework

I'm currently working in Linux, and I know you can use Run Process to run certain applications, but I was wondering if there's a possible way to have my script running, open command line, input, for example: "clean" which in my case processes a few functions in my bash.rc. That would be extremely helpful in my automation right now.

Comment: Can you [edit] your questsion with example code (for example the `Run Process` approach) and explain why this does not work for you?

Comment: Actually I got it! I made an executable .sh file and put my functions in there and used that to run it :)

Comment: then please share some elements of your solution and close the question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well essentially, what I did was I created a separate .sh executable file. Opened my .bashrc and copied my functions / aliases into my .sh file using the gedit editor. Then from my Robot Script, I used the Run Process command (I don't have my exact code at the moment) and called my executable file.